# Owncloud docker container not running (exec format error)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, owncloud

I’m starting owncloud on docker exactly as described here in the documentation: https://doc.owncloud.com/server/admin_manual/installation/docker/

Though it’s not starting and causing a “format exec error” in the docker logs.

**I’m running it on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (bionic) without GUI on an Odroid and docker version 18.09.5, build e8ff056.**

The docker-compose file is the same one as downloaded from the docs.

Envvars section looks like:

```
#set owncloud envvars
cat << EOF > .env
OWNCLOUD_VERSION=10.0
OWNCLOUD_DOMAIN=localhost
ADMIN_USERNAME=admin
ADMIN_PASSWORD=admin
HTTP_PORT=8082
EOF

sudo docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: could you please share error logs

Comment: @Prasobh.K docker logs owncloud just shows "exec format error"
maybe it's cause of the armv71 architecture?

Comment: binary and docker container should be of same platform..eg: you should build in windows and deploy in docker windows container..

Comment: @Prasobh.K So I need an armv container like: https://hub.docker.com/r/yangxuan8282/rpi-alpine-seafile/ ?